# Android Unity 3D Project java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo java.lang.nullpointerexception

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

I have following Android Unity 3D Project file that compiles but fail in runtime with java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo java.lang.nullpointerexception.
[image: runtime error message]

Here is the UnityPlayerNavtiveActivity.java

```
  package com.sniper.game;

  import com.unity3d.player.*;
  import android.app.NativeActivity;
  import android.content.res.Configuration;
  import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.KeyEvent;
  import android.view.MotionEvent;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.Window;
  import android.view.WindowManager;

  public class UnityPlayerNativeActivity extends NativeActivity
 {
 protected UnityPlayer mUnityPlayer;        // don't change the name of this variable; referenced from native code

// Setup activity layout
@Override protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().takeSurface(null);
    setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBX_8888); // <--- This makes xperia play happy

    mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(this);
    if (mUnityPlayer.getSettings ().getBoolean ("hide_status_bar", true))
        getWindow ().setFlags (WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                               WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(mUnityPlayer);
    mUnityPlayer.requestFocus();
}

// Quit Unity
@Override protected void onDestroy ()
{
    mUnityPlayer.quit();
    super.onDestroy();
}

// Pause Unity
@Override protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    mUnityPlayer.pause();
}

// Resume Unity
@Override protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    mUnityPlayer.resume();
}

// This ensures the layout will be correct.
@Override public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mUnityPlayer.configurationChanged(newConfig);
}

// Notify Unity of the focus change.
@Override public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
{
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    mUnityPlayer.windowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
}

// For some reason the multiple keyevent type is not supported by the ndk.
// Force event injection by overriding dispatchKeyEvent().
@Override public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)
{
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_MULTIPLE)
        return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event);
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}

// Pass any events not handled by (unfocused) views straight to UnityPlayer
@Override public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)     { return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event); }
@Override public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)   { return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event); }
@Override public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)          { return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event); }
/*API12*/ public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event)  {      return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event); }
}
```

Here is UnityPlayerActivity.java:

```
    package com.sniper.game;

    import com.unity3d.player.*;

 /**
 * @deprecated Use UnityPlayerNativeActivity instead.
 */
  public class UnityPlayerActivity extends UnityPlayerNativeActivity { }
```

Here is UnityPlayerProxyActivity.java:

```
package com.sniper.game;

import com.unity3d.player.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

/**
 * @deprecated Use UnityPlayerNativeActivity instead.
*/
public class UnityPlayerProxyActivity extends Activity
{
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,   com.sniper.game.UnityPlayerNativeActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null)
        intent.putExtras(extras);
    startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Here is the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="5" android:versionName="2.0" package="com.sniper.game" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
   <!-- Google Mobile Ads Permissions -->
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false">
    <!-- meta-data tag for Google Play services -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale" android:name="com.sniper.game.UnityPlayerProxyActivity">
    <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale" android:name="com.sniper.game.UnityPlayerActivity">
   </activity>
   <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale" android:name="com.sniper.game.UnityPlayerNativeActivity">
  <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
  </activity>
 <activity android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.unity3d.player.VideoPlayer">
 </activity>
 <!-- Google Mobile Ads Activity -->
 <activity android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity">
 </activity>
 </application>
 <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature   android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false" />
```

Here is the complete log trace ran few hours later from the screenshot above:

```
  05-15 14:14:03.840: D/AndroidRuntime(1583): Shutting down VM
  05-15 14:14:03.840: W/dalvikvm(1583): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1ac2b90)
  05-15 14:14:03.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1583): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  05-15 14:14:03.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1583): Process: com.sniper.game, PID: 1583
  05-15 14:14:03.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1583): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sniper.game/com.sniper.game.UnityPlayerNativeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
  05-15 14:14:03.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1583):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
  05-15 14:14:03.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1583):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
  05-15 14:14:03.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1583):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
  05-15 14:14:03.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1583):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
   05-15 14:14:03.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1583):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   05-15 14:14:03.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1583):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   05-15 14:14:03.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1583):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
   05-15 14:14:03.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1583):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   05-15 14:14:03.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1583):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   05-15 14:14:03.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1583):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
   05-15 14:14:03.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1583):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
   05-15 14:14:03.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1583):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   05-15 14:14:03.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1583): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   05-15 14:14:03.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1583):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1467)
   05-15 14:14:03.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1583):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1415)
   05-15 14:14:03.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1583):  at android.os.storage.IMountService$Stub$Proxy.mkdirs(IMountService.java:750)
   05-15 14:14:03.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1583):  at android.app.ContextImpl.ensureDirsExistOrFilter(ContextImpl.java:2160)
   05-15 14:14:03.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1583):  at android.app.ContextImpl.getObbDirs(ContextImpl.java:874)
   05-15 14:14:03.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1583):  at android.app.ContextImpl.getObbDir(ContextImpl.java:863)
   05-15 14:14:03.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1583):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getObbDir(ContextWrapper.java:220)
   05-15 14:14:03.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1583):  at android.app.NativeActivity.onCreate(NativeActivity.java:177)
   05-15 14:14:03.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1583):  at com.sniper.game.UnityPlayerNativeActivity.onCreate(UnityPlayerNativeActivity.java:22)
   05-15 14:14:03.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1583):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
   05-15 14:14:03.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1583):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
   05-15 14:14:03.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1583):  at       android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
   05-15 14:14:03.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1583):  ... 11 more
```

I need help in getting this Unity3D Android game running on simulator and then download and run on actual device.

Comment: Can you post a text version of the error log instead of a small screenshot that's hard to read?

Comment: @JohnWhite i posted the text version on error log.  Let me know if you can tell what is wrong with the code.

Comment: @user914425 have you found solution to this crash? I just saw one of these in Crashlytics. Just 1 user is affected (on Android 4.4.4), and the app is up for over a year. **Edit** I see that it's not an AdMob crash. Sorry. :|

Comment: have you found a solution @user914425? I also faced the same error.